# How to figure out memory utilisation of any PHP application?

Tags: cakephp, memory, memory-management

Is there any efficient way, by which i can check in & outs of the memory usage by the application code or functions. Right now in my application, it is eating up the RAM of the machine & not releasing the occupied memory. So can not be able to figure out what is happening there?

Cant understand is it a Memory leak or DB query overhead or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile your application with xdebug and use a tool like cachegrinder to analyze it.

- http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

This gives you exactly the data you're looking for.